# Set a default caption for ALL messagebox?

Tags: c#-4.0, messagebox

In c# 4.0 I would like to set, at an application level, a default caption for any message boxes the program creates. And by caption I mean the title of the message box.

So should a error message be displayed to the user they will all have the same title.
I know I can do it by using this Message Box overload:
MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, caption);

But I am wondering if there is a more crisp, clean, way to do it?
Rather than having to add a parameter to lots of calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really set a default. But you can make a helper to set the title for you, if you really want

```
public static class MessageBoxEx
{
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(message, "My Application Name");
    }
}
```

You can of course set the caption however you want, such as from a resource file for multiple languages and locales.

Comment: I was hoping for something more along the lines of C++ and AFX message boxes where you can set an application level title. Shame it seems to missing in C#.